OpenDaylight Error 401 Unauthorized, Suggestions? (I have already use differents ways to virtualize)
Using the next command:
$curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://172.17.0.2:8181/jolokia/read/org.opendaylight.controller:type=DistributedConfigDatastore,Category=ShardManager,name=shard-manager-config

I have the next error:
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/jolokia/read/org.opendaylight.controller:type=DistributedConfigDatastore,Category=ShardManager,name=shard-manager-config</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.jolokia.osgi.servlet.JolokiaServlet</td></tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>

using virtual machines (virtualbox 7.0 in windows) = Error401
using in native ubuntu 24.04 = Error401
using virtual machines in ubuntu = Error401
using in docker (with Ubuntu as native) = Error401
I do not know what to do next, suggestions?
I have tried using opendaylight in differents enviroments like docker, virtual machines (VirtualBox 7.0), Ubuntu (24.04 as native), etc.
I do not know what is the problems, even using sudo curl... I have the error, I research a little bit if the `admin:admin was wrong but I did not see some other credentials...
Please help!

Yes, this error is caused by the latest version of Open day light (calcium) 0.20.1, try with a previous version (0.20.0), The error can be caused by installing plugins on the openday light command line one by one, install all the plugins in a single line {feature:install} plugin plugin plugin. If you want to uninstall the plugins, try deleting the data folder inside karaf or delete all open day light and reinstall
